# If There are four 2's three 1's and two 0's how many was can you arange them in a 9 Digit number!

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If There are four 2's, three 1's and two 0's, in how many was can you arrange them in a 9 Digit number! Using Permutations only.
Show your answer is corrrect by counting it in three different ways and getting the same answer each time.

I Got :
p(9,4)*p(5,3)*P(2,2) =9! 
p(9,2)*p(7,3)*P(4,4) =9! 
p(9,3)*p(6,4)*P(2,2) =9!

Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
This is a standard problem for using the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient#Number_of_unique_permutations_of_words):

$$\binom{9}{4, 3, 2} = \binom{9}{4}\cdot \binom 53\cdot \binom 22 = \dfrac{9!}{4!\cancel{5!}} \cdot \frac{\cancel{5!}}{3!2!} \cdot \frac{\cancel{2!}}{\cancel{2!}} = \frac{9!}{4!\,3!\,2!}=1260$$

We have multiple occurrences of some digits, which can permute without changing the final number. So we need to divide by the number of ways each repeated digit can be permuted.

Comment: Needs a TU -->> +1

Answer (score 0):

9 numbers can be arranged in $9!$ ways, but since we cannot distinguish between different instances of 2, 1, and 0, arrangements which differ only by a permutations among these different instances of 2, 1 and 0, should be considered the same. This means that the number of arrangements times the number of ways in which the 2, 1 and 0 can be permuted among each other is the total number of permutations of 9 numbers, ie. 9!. If $N$ is your answer, then we must have $N \times 4! \times 3! \times 2 = 9!$, and so

$$
N = \frac{9!}{4! \times 3! \times 2!} = 1260
$$

Comment: Then is it doable with just combinations? How